# how to call received data in Serial Port C#

Tags: c#, serial-port

i'm newbie in C# serial port...

i have a virtual serial port driver and try this code...

```
 private string strPortData = null;

    private void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
                {
                    serialPort1.Open();
                }

                string strPortData= "CMD1";

                serialPort1.WriteLine(strPortData);

    }

    private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = serialPort1.ReadLine();
    }
```

but do not serialPort1_DataReceived ever call.

What should i do for call DataReceived?

Comment: `serialPort1.Dispose();` look very wrong for using asynchronous communication... You should be closing port when you done not as soon as you send command.

Comment: thank you @AlexeiLevenkov for your hint! but my Problem not solved yet.

Comment: @user3512208 Remove the serialPort1.Close(); statement altogether. You're closing it before any data has been returned like Alexei said.

Comment: oh! I've done something wrong. thank you @Matt. i edited that. but my problem is same!

Comment: What is your virtual serial port connected to?

Comment: my virtual Serial Port is connected to COM1 @Matt

Comment: Yes but what's on the other end to receive "CMD1" and send some data back?

Comment: i'll added a pair of virtual port COM1 and COM2. serialPort1 set on COM1.

Comment: @user3512208 Can you post all of your code then, including the code that has COM2 open, please? Are the virtual serial port drivers configured so that the two are connected together?

Comment: Dear @Matt! all code is same! and virtual serial port connected together. but COM2 is closed. how to open it? serialPort1 open COM1 because set on it. but COM2 how to open??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a new console application with code similar to the following

```
void Main()
{
    using (SerialPort serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1"))
    using (SerialPort serialPort2 = new SerialPort("COM2"))
    {
        serialPort1.DataReceived += (sender, args) => {
            Console.WriteLine("COM1 Received: " + serialPort1.ReadLine());
        };

        serialPort2.DataReceived += (sender, args) => {
            Console.WriteLine("COM2 Received: " + serialPort2.ReadLine());
        };

        serialPort1.Open();
        serialPort2.Open();

        serialPort1.WriteLine("Hello, COM2!");

        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
```

The above code opens both serial ports, sets up the data received events, and sends data through it. If you run that code you should see "COM2 Received: Hello, COM2!" output.

Comment: thanks a lot @Matt! it's worked! but in Line 11 serialPort2.ReadLine() is correct! You've helped me a lot. I wish you a good time.

Comment: @user3512208 Oops, good spot, I've edited my answer with your fix :)